# как в std::thread передать allocated класс?

Tags: c++

Работает, если класс создавать на стеке, но мне нужно создать интерфейс, ну типа базовый класс, то есть Factory по настоящему создает `new Binance`, а `binance` наследуется от `Market`. я думал что должно быть всё просто, но нет, опять какие то сложности, думал сделать код красивым, но нет, видимо на c++ можно писать только код, который не прикольный. хотя в цикле можно сделать создание класса в стеке, но может есть вариант создать из выделенной памяти?

```
#include <thread>
#include "Binance.hpp"
#include "Markets.hpp"
#include "Factory.hpp"

struct Params {
    const char *url;
    const unsigned short port;
    enum Markets type;
} Params[] = {
    { "wss://stream.binance.com/ws", 9443, Markets::BINANCE }
};

int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {

    const int sizeOfParams = sizeof (Params) / sizeof (struct Params);

    for ( int i = 0; i < sizeOfParams; i++ ) {
        Market *market = FactoryNewMarket ( Params[i].url, Params[i].port, Params[i].type );

        std::thread threadMarket ( market );

        threadMarket.detach ( );
    }
}
```

Comment: пока видно только жалобы на незнания плюсов и огрызок кода. К примеру, класс Market  совсем не понятен.

Comment: Но посмотрите на это со стороны класса thread - вы передаете ему какой то указатель на объект. Он не знает, что с ним делать. Но если написать функцию, которая принимает этот самый указатель, и передать ее первым параметром, а указатель вторым - все может получится.

Comment: @KoVadim в market определен оператор `void operator ( ) ( )`. то есть `std::thread` может вызвать класс `class.operator` и не в состоянии вызвать `class->operator`?

Comment: нет, не в состоянии. Но можно как минимум вот так написать `std::thread threadMarket ( [](Market*m) {(*m)();}, market );`

Comment: @KoVadim о блин, круто. короткая запись, то что нужно. а можете подсказать, как мне узнать о возможностях языка в стандартах 11 14 17 20? я слышал что есть черновики, но там вроде как я думаю, что не всё входит в стандарт, типа предложение по возможности языка, но потом думаю, вносить или нет. спасибо.

Comment: читать книги, статьи. Вот из последнего я читал https://litportal.ru/avtory/yacek-galovic-15687687/kniga-s-17-stl-standartnaya-biblioteka-shablonov-802416.html также классика - Майерс.